# Why do functions disabled by C++20 `requires` clauses still cause ill-formed type errors?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming

Working with C++20's `requires` statements, I've noticed that using `requires` to selectively disable a function definition breaks if a type in that function would be ill-formed -- even though the function is not enabled.

The simplest example I've found for this is anything with a `T&` where `T` may be `void`, for example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct maybe_void {
    maybe_void() requires(std::is_void_v<T>) = default;

    maybe_void(const T& v) requires(!std::is_void_v<T>) {}
    explicit maybe_void(int) {};
};

auto test() -> void {
    auto v = maybe_void<void>(42); // error -- sees 'const void&' constructor, even though it's disabled
}
```

All major compilers agree that this is an error:

- `gcc-trunk`:

  > ```
  > <source>:12:33:   required from here
  > <source>:7:5: error: forming reference to void
  >     7 |     maybe_void(const T& v) requires(!std::is_void_v<T>) {}
  >       |     ^~~~~~~~~~
  > ```
- `clang-trunk`:

  > ```
  > <source>:7:23: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
  >    maybe_void(const T& v) requires(!std::is_void_v<T>) {}
  >                      ^
  > <source>:12:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'maybe_void<void>' requested here
  >     auto v = maybe_void<void>(42);
  >              ^
  > ```
- `msvc-v19-latest`:

  > ```
  > <source>(7): error C2182: 'v': illegal use of type 'void'
  > <source>(12): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'maybe_void<void>' being compiled
  > ```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/anq3a63Yd)</kbd>

---

It was my understanding that `requires` was meant to work in cases like the above, but the various compilers seem to suggest otherwise. Why doesn't this work?

---

**Note:**

One possible workaround is to change the constructor to a constrained `template` instead:

```cpp
template <typename U>
explicit maybe_void(const U& v) requires(!std::is_void_v<U> && std::same_as<T,U>);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/v1Eq8rTaE)</kbd>

Although this works as a workaround, it doesn't explain why the `requires` clause doesn't prevent the otherwise disabled function from triggering the ill-formed issue in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the function *signature* is syntactically invalid. `void const &` is not a legitimate type in C++. So the compiler never gets to the `requires` clause for the function. It never gets to consider whether the function should or should not be discarded because the function is not a legal function signature.

The way this is generally dealt with is that you cull out `void` in the type. So you would need a separate specialization that allows `void`. Note that in most cases where a constructor would want to take a `T const&`, you'd have to do this anyway, because that function would almost certainly want to copy that `T` into a member variable or something. And you can't have a member variable of type `void`. So you'd still need a separate specialization.

If you do not otherwise need a specialization of your type to handle `void`, then you can create a type which, when given a `T` that is `void` results in an innocuous non-`void` type.

```
struct dont_use {};

template<typename T>
struct non_void { using type = T; };

template<>
struct non_void<void> { using type = dont_use; };

...

maybe_void(non_void_t<T> const& v) requires(!std::is_void_v<T>) {}
```

[As seen here](https://godbolt.org/z/rE1hW483s).